# RethinkDB r.polygon() - GeoJSON LinearRing must have at least four positions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, polygon, geojson, rethinkdb

I'm having an issue with inserting a geoJSON polygon into my database.

Here's the data I'm trying to insert:

```
{
    "feature": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -71.17351189255714,
                    42.350224666504324
                ],
                [
                    -71.1677360907197,
                    42.34671571695422
                ],
                [
                    -71.16970919072628,
                    42.35326835618748
                ],
                [
                    -71.14341516047716,
                    42.36174674733808
                ],
                [
                    -71.17559093981981,
                    42.368232175909064
                ],
                [
                    -71.17351189255714,
                    42.350224666504324
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {}
    },
    "name": "New Polygon"
}
```

Here's the code I'm trying to execute:

```
r.table( 'homebases' ).insert( {
    xid: data.xid,
    name: data.name,
    geoType: "polygon",
    geoPoly: r.geojson( data.feature.geometry )
} ).run().then( function ( doc ) {
    return res.send( doc.generated_keys[ 0 ] )
} ).error( function ( err ) {
    console.error( err.message )
    return res.send( 500, err.message )
} )
```

I'm getting this error:

```
GeoJSON LinearRing must have at least four positions
```

I'm not too sure what's going on here, as I'm able to do the exact same with a geoJSON point and it works great. It says in the API docs that I can add a 'type': 'Polygon' geoJSON object.

I tried searching everywhere but couldn't find any solutions. I'm not too sure how to proceed with this one. Any help at all would greatly be appreciated!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The input data is not a valid GeoJSON polygon.

From the spec [1]:

> For type "Polygon", the "coordinates" member must be an array of LinearRing coordinate arrays.

So let's look at what a "LinearRing coordinate array" is [2]:

> A LinearRing is closed LineString with 4 or more positions. The first and last positions are equivalent (they represent equivalent points). Though a LinearRing is not explicitly represented as a GeoJSON geometry type, it is referred to in the Polygon geometry type definition.

To make it short, the input data you mention here is missing one nested array in the `coordinates` field. The `coordinates` of a Polygon must be *an array of arrays* of coordinates. This is so that you can construct a polygon with holes in it (the first LinearRing in the Polygon is the outside edge, any subsequent LinearRings in the `coordinates` array will be considered holes).

The following should work:

```
{
    "feature": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -71.17351189255714,
                        42.350224666504324
                    ],
                    [
                        -71.1677360907197,
                        42.34671571695422
                    ],
                    [
                        -71.16970919072628,
                        42.35326835618748
                    ],
                    [
                        -71.14341516047716,
                        42.36174674733808
                    ],
                    [
                        -71.17559093981981,
                        42.368232175909064
                    ],
                    [
                        -71.17351189255714,
                        42.350224666504324
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {}
    },
    "name": "New Polygon"
}
```

[1] http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon

[2] http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring

Comment: that is a great catch there! I can't believe I missed that one.

I generated my polygon by using turf.js
[Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_polygon.html)
and overlooked the format knowing how consistent turf has been for me. Thank you for the help!!!